# Route traffic to LAN IP via a public server

Tags: networking, routing

I'm trying to setup a homelab server that can be accessed from externally from anywhere. My assumption was that my ISP provides me a dynamic IP that I can work around with [Duck DNS](https://www.duckdns.org/)

Unfortunately, it seems that my ISP using [carrier-grade nat](https://carrier-grade%20nat.), so that is not an option.

[image: Current network diagram]

I do have a small public server with limited capacity that has a static IP. Is there a way I can connect it to be a part of my LAN and then route traffic through it to my homelab server?

Comment: The only way I see is to install / configure a VPN server on your public server and connect to this VPN **from** your Homelab. - You can use `wireguard` or `OpenVPN` for that.